# ERROR running force:source:retrieve: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined VS Code

Tags: metadata, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, manifest

I am trying to retrieve the Salesforce metadata in VS Code with the below command,

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x ./manifest/package.xml
```

This was working fine prior to today, but suddenly I have started getting the below error:

> ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  Cannot read property 'id' of
> undefined

I have recreated the project repository and tried this again, but no success.

Below is the package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>ApexClassName</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

How can the above error be resolved. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please share your package.xml file?

Comment: The package.xml is the same as before when it was working. Anyways I have added it to the question now

Comment: Did you try updating salesforcedx? Command: sfdx update

Comment: Yes, its updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was occuring due to Salesfoce CLI update.

It has been resolved with the latest release 7.115.0

Refer [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1138) for details on the issue and resolution

Comment: I'm getting this error as of 2/22/22 using latest sfdx-cli (7.138.1). Any ideas/advice?