# Error while Authorizing an ORG using VS Code Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setContentsFromObject')

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin, login-errors, authorization, sfdx-error

Created a New Project in vs code
SFDX- Create Project

SFDX-Authorize Org

when i try to i get error

[image]
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setContentsFromObject')

This is most likely not an error with the Salesforce CLI. Please ensure all information is accurate and try again.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354018/error-running-forcesourceretrieve-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined-vs-c  Does this answer your question?

Comment: I tried to update using sfdx update stable-rc, still same error while authorizing

Comment: I'm getting this error while authorizing a specific playground. (Other playgrounds & dev orgs are getting authorized).

Comment: Tried to Authorize the Playground in another machine/Pc and it's getting Authorized. Why such error for my machine?

Comment: sfdx force:auth:device:login This doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Try going to the .sfdx folder under Users/[name]/.sfdx and delete everything in there. I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: This also fixed it for me

Comment: I tried this but it is not working... Can someone please help me?

Comment: But I have 27 different orgs in there and the other 26 are fine.  I've tried deleting all references to the failing org, but it still fails and everyone else still works. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can also just delete the file for your specific org, if you have multiple, instead of deleting everything.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

One of my students recently experienced this out of nowhere. We attempted the fixes listed here and I noticed that they could be elaborated a bit to help others since we got a little confused. Here are the steps we took to resolve it:

1. Ran sfdx update stable-rc
2. Closed VSCode
3. Went to C:/Users/[name]/.sfdx and deleted all contents within (this could be a different drive depending on where you installed CLI)
4. Restarted VSCode and attempted to connect to an org

This was successful in resolving the issue.